# Automating Data Extract from Dashboard in Tableau using Rest API

Tags: python, rest, tableau-api

I am trying to write a python script which will automate the extraction of data from Tableau dashboard using Rest API, but I am getting the error that I am unable to sign in to tableau server, below is my script, can anyone please help me here?

```
import csv
import tableauserverclient as TSC

def get_site_credentials():
    """ 
    This function will read files and passes back credentials for sign in.
    Returns user, toke,site
    """

    with open('C:\\Users\\Documents\\Tableau_pyth\\token.txt') as file:
        token = file.read()

    with open('C:\\Users\\Documents\\Tableau_pyth\\user.txt') as file:
        user = file.read()

    with open('C:\\Users\\Documents\\Tableau_pyth\\path.txt') as file:
        site = file.read()

    return(user, token, site)

def dashboard_views(workbookname, tableau_auth, server):
    """ 
    Takes in a work book name and gives back populated view
    Arguments:
    workbookname - string name of workbook to be matched
    tableau_auth - string authentication of the session
    server- string server instance of the session
    """

    req_option = TSC.RequestOptions()
    req_option.filter.add(TSC.Filter(TSC.RequestOptions.Field.Name,
                                     TSC.RequestOptions.Operator.Equals,
                                     workbookname))
    
    matching_workbooks, pagination_item = server.workbooks.get(req_option)
    wbmatch = matching_workbooks[0]
    server.workbooks.get_by_id(wbmatch.id)
    server.workbooks.populate_views(wbmatch, usage = True)
    output = [ view for view in wbmatch.views]
    return output

creds = get_site_credentials()
tableau_auth = TSC.PersonalAccessTokenAuth(creds[0], creds[1],creds[2])
server = TSC.Server('https://prodad.online.tableau.com', use_server_version= True)

with server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth):
    mviews = dashboard_views('Sales Figures', tableau_auth, server)
    for view in mviews:
        if view.name != 'Inflation Index over Time':
                server.views.populate_csv(view)
                with open(' {}.csv'.format(view.name),'wb')as f:
                     #Perform byte join on the csv data
                         f.write(b''.join(view.csv))

        else:
              print('No data output written for view named {}'.format(view.name))
```

Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 0):

Check your creds order and values. The API doc states for token auth is:

`PersonalAccessTokenAuth(token_name, personal_access_token, site_id='')`

https://tableau.github.io/server-client-python/docs/api-ref#authentication

Comment: I followed the document and changed the authorization as instructed, it worked as expected. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I changed the following piece of code from this:

```
tableau_auth = TSC.PersonalAccessTokenAuth(creds[0], creds[1],creds[2])
```

to this:

```
tableau_auth = TSC.PersonalAccessTokenAuth('user_id','password',site_id ='')
site_id = [name which comes after /site/ in the url]
```